# Adjust image size in popup to fit inside popup container

Tags: leaflet, popup, image

I would like to display images in popups. It works but the problem is the images are too large:

[image]

I've added a class in the img tag in my js-file:

```
var picURL2 = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg';

shelter1.bindPopup("<img src='" + picURL2 + "'" + "class=popupImage" + "/>");
```

The class in my css file looks like this:

```
.popupImage {
    max-width: 20%;
    max-height: 20%;
}
```

But the image still streches beyond the popup container. The console doesn't produce any errors so I assume I've added the class inside the img tag correctly.

Comment: How about if you put a <div> around the img and give that div a size. Maybe the img's current parent does not have a declared width to calculate the 20% of. (Spoken without having used leaflet.) That's in the spirit of figuring it out, as of course at that point you may as well explicitly set width or height of the img.

Comment: I've added the class like this (still not working): shelter1.bindPopup("<div class=popupImageContainer>" + "<img src='" + picURL2 + "'" + "/>" + "</div>");. Also tried to use styles inside the img tag and define height and width. Didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two spaces missing. The first one is not critical but the second one is. It should be:

```
shelter1.bindPopup("<img src='" + picURL2 + "'" + " class=popupImage " + "/>");
```

Comment: The spaces did the trick!. The image adjusts down in size. However, when I set the max-width and max-height to 300% or above the image stretches beyond the popup container. Have used width/height and adjusted in margins but the image still stretches beyond the container.

Comment: So I came up with a solution. In my CSS-file I created a container: .popupContainer {width: 200px; height: 200px;} and then added the image width in the container class: .popupContainer image {width: 100%;}